# If value exist head to location

Tags: php, html, function

I want my form to redirect to index2.html without inserting values or carrying out case function if email already exists in database. I have tried several approach without success. Here is my function.php

```
<?php

require 'database.php';

$title  = $_POST['Title'];
$fullname   = $_POST['fullname'];
$email  = $_POST['email'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];

$sql = "SELECT email FROM tbl_users WHERE email = $email";
$result = dbQuery($sql);
if (dbNumRows($result) == 1) {
    header ('Location: index2.php');
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_users (Title, fullname, email, gender)
        VALUES ('$title', '$fullname', '$email', '$gender')";   
dbQuery($sql);

switch ( $_POST['gender'] )
{
    case 'male':
        header('Location: male.php');
        break;
    case 'female':
        include 'female.php';
        break;
    }
?>
```

While my form

```
<form action="function.php" method="post
    <input name="Title" placeholder="Title" type="text">
    <input name="fullname" placeholder="fullname" type="text">
    <input name="email" placeholder="email" type="text">
    <select name="gender">
        <option selected="selected" value="-">Please select your bank</option>
        <option value="male">Male</option>
        <option value="female">Female</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you receive an error?

Comment: `exit();` after your location change

Answer (score 2):

put your insert query in else
Example -

```
if (dbNumRows($result) == 1) {
        header ('Location: index2.php');
    }else {

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_users (Title, fullname, email, gender)
            VALUES ('$title', '$fullname', '$email', '$gender')";   
    dbQuery($sql);
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

After redirecting, you need to exit PHP, or it's going to read and execute the rest of your code. So simply this should fix the issue:

```
header('Location: index2.php');
die();
```

Comment: Why use `die()` and not `exit`? `die()` is a error reporting function and will possibly produce an entry in your error log.

Comment: die() and exit() are equivalent, so either is fine.

Comment: Okay. There are some languages where it is not, so I prefer (and recommend) to use `die` only in cases of failure, and `exit` at success.

Answer (score 2):

If this is really part of your code

```
WHERE email = $email";
```

Your code/header is failing because it wasn't quoted:

```
WHERE email = '$email'";
```

since `$email` is a string and not an integer.

You also need to add an `exit;` after **each** header, otherwise your code will want to continue to execute.

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

You're open to an SQL injection; use a prepared statement.

References:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Plus, if `<form action="function.php" method="post` is (again) part of your real code, it's missing both a quote `"` and a closing `>` for it.

```
<form action="function.php" method="post">
```

---

Footnotes:

The API used to connect/query with is unknown, so check for errors on the query and via PHP with error reporting.

You should also check for any empty fields. Otherwise you may get unexpected results/surprises.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

---

> *"I want my form to redirect to index2.html"*

and you're using (with `.php`)

```
header ('Location: index2.php');
```

You may have made a typo with one of those. If not, then use the `.html` extension, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: I just typed the code for simplicity. They are intact in the actual code.

Comment: @JaphetSmith When people post code, I take it literally as it may be (part of) the real problem so I don't take any chances ;-) and this for future visitors to the question/answer(s).

Comment: @JaphetSmith something I don't understand though, is why you're doing a header on `case 'male':
        header('Location: male.php');` but an include for `case 'female':
        include 'female.php';`. Go over my answer again and check for errors. There isn't anything else I can add to it.